# Как пересчитать вес сортировки?

Tags: php

Идея такая:
Есть набор данных в отсортированном варианте:

```
id|weght
2 | 110
1 | 100
3 | 100
```

Теперь я хочу, чтобы 3 был выше 2, но при это добавляя к 3 не 20, а 10.

То-есть мне нужно пересчитать все значения, чтобы на выходе получить:

```
    id|weght
    3 | 110
    2 | 100
    1 | 100
```

Как написать такую универсальную функцию?)

Comment: Если веса равны, то сравнивать по id. `if ($a['weght'] == $b['weght']) return $a['id'] - $b['id']; `

Comment: @ArchDemon спасибо. Но тут нельзя использовать id. 
То-есть сортировка должна быть только по значению веса. Ну и соответственно нужно переписать в нужных значениях вес.

Comment: Если нельзя id, то как знать как сортировать его? И id эти могут быть ключами массива? Не пойму в каком формате этот набор данных.

Comment: Сортировать только по весу. 
Ну например. 
У нас есть базово массив [1 => 110, 2 => 100, 3 => 100];
Я указываю, что 2 нужно поднять над 1. 
Если я прибавляю к 2 +10 - то значения будут равны. 
Соответственно мне нужно понизить значение у 1 -10 и у 2 добавить +10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На скорую руку накатал решение, надеюсь правильно Вас понял.

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'weight' => 100
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'weight' => 110
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'weight' => 100
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    'id' => 3, // К какому элементу прибавляем вес
    'addedWeight' => 10 // На сколько прибавляем
];

$key = array_search($array2['id'], array_column($array, 'id'));
$array[$key]['weight'] += $array2['addedWeight'];

foreach ($array as $key2 => ['id' => $id, 'weight' => $weight]) {
    if ($key2 !== $key && $weight === $array[$key]['weight']) {
        $array[$key2]['weight'] -= $array2['addedWeight'];
    }
}

usort($array, fn($a, $b): int => $b['weight'] <=> $a['weight']);
```

Визуализируем

```
echo 'id|weight' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($array as ['id' => $id, 'weight' => $weight]) {
    echo $id . '|' . $weight . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]